# Bring my right sidebar to the top of my page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Since centring my blog content my right hand sidebar has fallen down below my content.

How can I bring it back it up so it sits to the right of my page? (Between the right side border and the edge of the page).

Live link:
https://www.moneynest.co.uk/how-to-choose-a-broker/

Code:

```
<html>
<body class="post-template-default single single-post postid-594 single-format-standard logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support nolayout windows chrome override" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><div class="site-container">
<div class="site-inner">    
    <div class="content">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="central-container">
                <div class="middle-content">
                <div class="inner-post-head">
                </div>
                    <div class="data-content">
    <!--MAIN CONTENT HERE -->         
                  </div><!-- End .middle-content -->
    </div>
        </div><!-- End #container -->
  </div><!-- End #content -->
     <aside class="sidebar sidebar-primary widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="Primary Sidebar" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar" id="genesis-sidebar-primary"><h2 class="genesis-sidebar-title screen-reader-text">Primary Sidebar</h2><section id="text-9" class="widget widget_text"><div class="widget-wrap">          <div class="textwidget">
 <!--SIDE BAR CONTENT HERE--></div>
  <!--<div id="popular-articles">
    <p class="popular-articles-text">Popular articles</p>
  </div>-->
</div>
</div>
        </div>
<section id="text-10" class="widget widget_text"><div class="widget-wrap"   
        </div></section>
        </div>
        </aside>
<!--END OF SIDEBAR--!>
<!--FOOTER STUFF-->
        </body>
</html>
```

Running Wordpress with custom Genesis theme and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style sheet is having below code

```
.site-inner, .wrap {
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

As you have centered your contents with margin-left, this 1200px is not enough to hold your sidebar. SO please change that to below one so that it will work for you

```
.site-inner, .wrap {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Method 2: 
 Make your content part centralized through out and make your sidebar positioned to right side. Style as follows:

```
.site-inner{
position: relative;
}
.content {
width: 792px;
margin: 0 auto !important;
float: none;
}
.sidebar-primary {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px !important;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've applied Method 1 & 2. which worked great apart from a lot of padding appearing between the content and sidebar. How can I remove this?

Comment: Rather than remove basically, what I'm saying is how can I center the sidebar within the right side?

Comment: For that i think you have to divide the website layout into three as left sidebar content and then right sidebar. By keeping your left sidebar blank you can have the same layout with proper padding between the content part and right sidebar.

Make your left sidebar to have equal height of content div, to have the blank part extend through out the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
```

or instead make it thinner (width:80%) and give the content display: inline

Answer (score 0):

As well as removing the left margin from .content, I'd also recommend removing padding from .site-inner and adding `margin:0 auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in your page and did this. It is working. Just decrease your margin-left property in relative media queries.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px)
(index):27
.content {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```